# SQL Server name in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to declare SQL Server name in a variable so that I can run query on any server by just changing server name.

```
DECLARE @ServerName NVARCHAR(100)
SET @ServerName = 'dbServer'

[@ServerName].[dbo].[Product]
```

Comment: That doesn't work in SQL Server.

Comment: Although linked servers _seem_ to solve a lot of issues, they don't scale well and they can have security concerns if not setup properly.

Answer (score 1):

Macro substitutions, as in your SQL code, are not supported in SQL Server.

A possible solution is to use dynamic SQL. However, do beware of SQL injection when using this technique  ; do not set the variable from a POSTed value.

```
DECLARE @ServerName nvarchar(100)
SET @ServerName = 'dbServer';

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) 
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * From ' + QUOTENAME(@ServerName) + '.[dbo].[Product]'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Central Management Servers** to do this.

Here is official documentation [Create a Central Management Server and Server Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group?view=sql-server-2017)

[Execute Statements Against Multiple Servers Simultaneously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously?view=sql-server-2017)

And here is more detailed example with the pictures: [Execute SQL Server query on multiple servers at the same time](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1767/execute-sql-server-query-on-multiple-servers-at-the-same-time/)

Onced you've set up `Central Management Servers` you can execute your statements on all of these servers.
It's very usefull for administrator's tasks when you want to control job executions, etc on all of your servers.